# search for files using regex list files only include single quotes

Tags: regex, linux

I got list of files inside folders need to list only files name that include single quotes

like image1'.jpg

i used

```
find -regex  /home/san/"'.jpg" >> /tmp/output.txt
```

What do i miss here

Comment: Did you try `find /home/san/ -name ".jpg" >> /tmp/output.txt`

Comment: its list all jpg files i need to list only files that include single quote in their names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man find` says:

```
   -regex pattern
          File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search...
```

You probably want:

```
find /home/san -type f -name "*'*"
```

Comment: But the `-name` option doesn't work with regular expressions. You need only globbing, without the dots.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for files that contain an apostrophe, you can use this:

```
find -regex "/home/san/.*'.*"
```